# OpenID login to Facebook w/ custom OP Provider working/broken?

Tags: facebook, openid

I've got a custom OpenID provider that I'd like to use to log in to Facebook. I go to set up my Linked Account, select "OpenID..." and type in the identifier of my OpenID provider (I've tried this with both the OP Identifier and the user-specific Claimed Identifier). I get a bit of a delay, a pop-up, and then "Not a valid OpenID url" as the error message.

I do not see ANY traffic hitting my OpenID provider at all (no XRDS request, etc). I have also verified that I can use my custom provider with other sites that accept OpenID (StackOverflow, the OpenID site itself, etc).

It looks like there was some initial discussions about this support from when it came out and then I see some Facebook Developer Forum discussions asking if it's broken, with no resolution. So, does this work for anyone? If so, can anyone suggest how to troubleshoot this, as I don't see ANY traffic hitting my endpoint? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. It's working for my OpenID. You might try associating a "stock" OpenID from someone like https://myvidoop.com or https://myopenid.com and if that works, then proceed to troubleshoot your own. That will at least establish that it's not some goofy account configuration issue with your Facebook account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending your Provider through these tests:

http://test-id.org/OP/ReturnToVerification.aspx

If they all succeed, then Facebook probably has a whitelist of Providers they're willing to use.

But FWIW, AFAIK Facebook was toying with this OpenID RP idea a long time back and hasn't touched it since, so it's probably a dead feature.